# what is `dart.js` in chartjs.dart example

Tags: javascript, dart, chart.js, dart-js-interop

I am learning `[package:js][1]` and reading the [example](https://github.com/google/chartjs.dart/tree/master/example) here.

I am curious what is `dart.js` 
 here https://github.com/google/chartjs.dart/blob/master/example/index.html#L7 and what it is used for?

Any hints welcomed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That looks like it's using the older interface.  Things have changed a lot since then.  The modern angular rewrites everything on the fly so that those things are no longer needed in your source HTML.

Answer (score 0):

It is the JavaScript output generated by `dart2js` when you build a Dart web project using `pub build` (Dart 1).

For Dart 2 `build` is used instead and the `browser` and `dart_to_js_script_rewriter` packages are no longer necessary.

See also 
- https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/build_runner
- https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/build